# Search inside a post on SE Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

A question has a half dozen answers, and I lack time to read them all in detail. On desktop, I typically cope with this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find a particular word in the page. In Chrome for Android, the overflow menu has an item "Find in page".

I could not find a corresponding command in Stack Exchange app for Android on my Samsung Galaxy Tab A.

It would be great if we can search inside a post like that.

Comment: Not yet available, other than opening the post in browser. Consider change it to [tag:feature-request]

Comment: In addition of that, searching `inquestion:[question_id] search term` (e.g. [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A3122%20android)) won't return anything on the app. It seems, the app only searches for questions, as no answers are returned.